# Using Multiple Conditions with Count - LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

All,

I cannot seem to figure this out. I looked [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) and tried some different lambda expressions but to no avail. I am trying to do this for my condition:

```
(DateOrganized >= startDate.Date && DateOrganized <= endDate.Date)
```

This is all I have that will compile. How can I add another condition like above? Thanks

```
r.Count(x => x.DateOrganized <= endDate.Date);
```

**This does not compile**

```
r.Count(x => x.DateOrganized >= startDate.Date && x => x.DateOrganized <= endDate.Date);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
r.Count(x => (x.DateOrganized >= startDate.Date) &&
             (x.DateOrganized <= endDate.Date));
```